# How to define an "On/Off" Check box in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, checkbox

I want to design a layout having a checkbox similar to the image below

[image]

How do I achieve this.

I tried the following but it's not the result I want :

```
          <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="On"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Comment: you want it exactly like that or is switch good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html):

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Play with the Switch" />
```

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html):

> A Switch is a two-state toggle switch widget that can select between two options

Switches are functionally similar to check boxes, but look different. A full layout example can be found [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/android-switch-button-example.html).

---

As `Der Golem` pointed out, you could also use the older [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html). Here is a comparison of the two:

#### Switch

[image: A Switch in Android]

#### Toggle Button

[image]

Comment: Earlier Android versions can use the [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html), instead.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use a Switch in earlier versions of android. Is it available in the support library?

Comment: @user3548323 you may just want to use a Toggle Button instead if you are using a lower sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all its not a checkbox its a switch in android 
**credit to mysamplecode.com for code since i couldnt post the link
as example:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Play with the Switch" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView switchStatus;
private Switch mySwitch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

    //set the switch to ON 
    mySwitch.setChecked(true);
    //attach a listener to check for changes in state
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
            }else{
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
            }

        }
    });

    //check the current state before we display the screen
    if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
        switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
    }
    else {
        switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```